# Generation a pointer-to-member function or a member matching another declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming

This particular method was used in code to bridge a generic algorithm and some generated class implementations (represented here by class B):

```
// A class generated by outside source
struct B {
    void foo(int);
    void foo();

    int bar();
    int bar() const;

    float blah(int) const;
};

#define DECLARE_METHOD_TYPE(TName, CName, Func)    \
     template<typename ...Args>                    \
     using TName = decltype(                       \
     std::declval<CName>().Func(std::declval<Args>() ...)) \
         (CName::*) (Args...)

#define METHOD_PTR(TName, ... ) static constexpr TName<__VA_ARGS__>

// A bridge
struct A 
{
    DECLARE_METHOD_TYPE(FooPtr, B, foo);

    // need both declaration
    DECLARE_METHOD_TYPE(BarPtr, B, bar);
    DECLARE_METHOD_TYPE(BarPtrConst, B, bar) const;

    // must be const
    DECLARE_METHOD_TYPE(BlahPtrConst, B, blah) const;

    METHOD_PTR(FooPtr, int) b_foo_n = &B::foo;
    METHOD_PTR(FooPtr)      b_foo   = &B::foo;

    METHOD_PTR(BarPtr)      b_bar   = &B::bar;
    METHOD_PTR(BarPtrConst) b_cbar  = &B::bar;

    // must be exact
    METHOD_PTR(BlahPtrConst, int) b_blah = &B::blah;
};
```

Is there w way to declare each pointer in a single statement? main problem there is that the pointer type is a template and I need a unique typename for it.

Or is there a way to create a macro that generates member function which would call B's member (like a visitor). I think, I can declare such function, but I cannot define it.

Comment: I don't understand, can't you just get rid of the `using` and spell the type directly? As for generating unique names, you do that by concatenating `__COUNTER__` to something, but I don't see why it's needed here.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oh, I didn't knew that macro, at least, thanks for info. As of getting rid of `using`,I can't figure out if I can declare a template of variable here this way. Maybe it's just evening of Friday for me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a template of method would have an argument of type T, it can select a proper overload based on argument list:

```
template<class C, typename ...Args>
auto CallFoo(C&& c, Args... args) ->  decltype( c.foo(args...) )
{
    return c.foo(args...);
}
```

The implementation which appears to work:

```
#include <iostream>

#define DECLARE_METHOD( Name, CName, func )  \
    template<class CName, typename ...Args> \
    auto Name(CName&& c, Args... args) ->  decltype( c.func (args...)  ) \
        { return  c.func (args...); }     

struct B {
    int foo(int i) { return i; };
    void foo() {};

    int bar()        { return -42; };
    int bar() const  { return 42; };

    float blah(int i) const { return 42 / i; }
};

struct A 
{
    DECLARE_METHOD(CallFoo, B, foo)
    DECLARE_METHOD(CallBar, B, bar)
    DECLARE_METHOD(CallBlah, B, blah)
};

int main()
{
   A a;
   B b;
   const B cb;

   std::cout <<    a.CallFoo(b, 2);
   std::cout <<    a.CallBar(b); 
   std::cout <<    a.CallBar(cb);
   std::cout <<    a.CallBlah(b, 2); 
}
```