# With C++ CRTP, how do I infer the parameters of a function in the derived class?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, functor, crtp

I'm trying to infer the return type and args of a function from within the CRTP base class in order to "wrap" functors.

Starting with the basic CRTP pattern:

```cpp
template<typename Deriv>
struct Function
{
  int func(int a, int b) 
  { 
    return static_cast<Deriv*>(this)->func(a, b); 
  }
};

struct Add : Function<Add>
{
  int func(int a, int b) 
  { 
    return a + b; 
  }
};
```

This compiles but is not very generic of course!  So let's take it further:

```
template<typename Deriv, typename R, typename ...Args>
struct Function
{
  R func(Args&&... args) 
  { 
    return static_cast<Deriv*>(this)->func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
  }
};

struct Add : Function<Add, int, int, int> // R = int, Args... = int, int
{
  int func(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
};
```

But this repeats itself when specifying `R = int` and `Args = int, int`.  So how can I deduce these? For example:

```cpp
template<typename Deriv>
struct Function
{
  Helper<Deriv>::R func(Helper<Deriv>::Args ...args) 
  { 
    return static_cast<Deriv*>(this)
      ->func(std::forward<Helper<Deriv>::Args>(args)...); 
  }
};

struct Add : Function<Add> // Much cleaner
{
  int func(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
};
```

I realize that at the time that Base is instantiated, the definition of `Add::func` is not known... That's the issue I suppose.

I have looked at this, which recommends traits: [How to infer the type in CRTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241741/how-to-infer-the-type-in-crtp)

But this would mean I'd have to define the `R`/`Args...` in a trait and then define the function again later.

And I'm trying to make things "DRY" so I don't repeat myself, which means I only want to have `int func(int, a, int b) { return a + b; }` (its types/signature) defined once.

Comment: Note that none of your examples does compile so that might confuse.

Comment: "I have looked at this, which recommends traits" the question you link has no accepted answer, theres not even a "top answer" because they all have 0 votes

Comment: "But this would mean I'd have to define the R/Args... in a trait and then define the function again later." I dont understand the issue you see. The trait is not using a explicit specialization where you need to list all `R/Args` for each possible `Base` but the trait simply infers `R/Args` from any given type. There is no repetition

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9h7s9ePbK). There are both `using type = int(int, int);` and `int func(int, int)`.

Comment: This is because you are using a specialization for a trait. You should instead use something like `boost::function_traits` (of course it doesn't work as-is because it is a member function not a free function, but the point is that the trait should be general), which doesn't require specialization, hence no repeating of yourself.

Comment: @WeijunZhou: You cannot have generic traits on incomplete types though. Either it is complete, and a generic function_traits might extract information from the type, or it is incomplete, and you have to provide (and so repeat) the information of that class once complete.

Comment: That's true, so it is basically impossible in the context of "traditional" CRTP, as your answer correctly indicates. I am not entirely sure whether it's possible if the CRTP is instead implemented with c++23 "deducing this". If it is possible, you can consider adding that to your answer.

Comment: @WeijunZhou: "deducing this" allows to get rid of some CRTP. Hard to propose something useful though as OP example is over simplified and `func` adds nothing...

Answer (score 4):

Within CRTP, `Deriv` is incomplete.
Retrieving signature of `Deriv::func` requires complete type.

One way is to not use CRTP and use regular hierarchy:

```
template <auto M>
struct Function;

template <typename Base, typename Ret, typename... Args, Ret (Base::*M) (Args...)>
struct Function<M> : Base
{
    Ret func(Args... args) {
        return (this->*M)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

And then

```
struct Add_Impl
{
  int func(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
};

using Add = Function<&Add_Impl::func>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z1KWfjnzo)

Answer (score 3):

In short, what you're trying to do is impossible. When the CRTP class is instantiated through inheritance in `struct Add : Function<Add>`, the `Deriv = Add` given to it is incomplete. No information such as the signature of `Add::func` can be extracted from it.

Even if it could, the syntax `Deriv::R func(Deriv::Args... args)` would be broken because `Deriv` is not a template parameter pack, so it cannot be expanded. Using a helper template `Helper<Deriv>::Args` cannot work either. You could store `Args` as a `std::tuple`, but using tuples probably isn't what you want.

#### Bad workaround - `Function::func` template

If `Function::func` was a member function template, then you could omit specifying any parameters in the signature.
Everything could be deduced.

```cpp
template<typename Deriv>
struct Function
{
  template<class... Args>
    requires requires (Deriv& d, Args&&... args) {
      // note: if func was a call operator, you could use std::invocable as a
      //       requirement instead of this
      d.func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
  decltype(auto) func(Args&&... args) 
  {
    return static_cast<Deriv*>(this)->func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
  }
};
```

The return type is deduced, and the function is callable with parameters of any type, however, it is constrained so only valid calls to `Deriv::func` can be made through `Function::func`.

The obvious downside is that `Function::func` is now a template, and significantly more complex than `Add::func`.

There are other bad workarounds such as using macros, but they're arguably even worse for code quality.

Comment: This is not that bad. Not worse than `std::function` at any rate.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI an implementaion of one that I saw used some kind of CRTP with a helper class which was dependin on what kid of callable `std::function` stores. That allowed end-and-chicken problem solution at the cost of compexity.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I'm sorry I think I was too fast to comare this to std::function. It's more like std::thread constructor and the like. You get a callable and a list of arguments but there is no way to derive arguments from the callable, so they must remain generic.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI yeah, macro method or mking it absolutely gebneric sucks., I saw that, one only may try to offer user to choose right arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76741051/generation-a-pointer-to-member-function-or-a-member-matching-another-declaration

Answer (score 0):

It's same situation as with types based on `Deriv`. You have to have a third template type instantiated depending on `typename Deriv`, which would define func in a specialization for concrete class (e.g. `Deriv=Add`) and be complete at the moment of instantiation of `Function<Add>`.

At this point the code is compex enough that there should a be a good explanation why it even is required.